# document property of frame object doesn't work if frame uses external source?

Tags: javascript

when i tried to retrieve some data from external resource i encountered with interesting thing. When i use it with my own website it works correct,but with external resource it doesn't.

```
   doc = parent.Frame2.document;  
   alert(doc);
```

the source of `Frame2` is main page of the website where this script executes and i get message "Object HTML Document"

But when i change the source to another one for example

it was :
`<frame name='Frame2' src="mysite.com'>`     i changed it to smth like:

```
<frame name="Frame2" src="http://cnn.com"/>
```

and got `"undefined"`. Why is that? Can anybody explain it?

I tried also     `contentDocument`     and     `windowDocument`     as it's descirbed in bunch of similar 
questions, but still no luck. I'm just beginner and i hope that someone will explain it to me or maybe suggest other methods i may use to achieve success in this matter and i also hope that someone will find it useful.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering the [**same-origin policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

This is a security feature to prevent malicious websites from accessing private data from other websites and applies to [*XMLHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)s as well as `<iframe>`s.

The way to achieve success would be via using your server to proxy the page via some script, or setting up [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).
CORS applies mainly to *XMLHttpRequest* (I think browsers ignore it in `<iframe>`s) and requires you to have control over the HTTP headers sent by the server to you want to retrieve data from, as you need to send a specific header allowing your site (or all websites by wildcard `*`).